# How to prevent function with parameters from being called on page load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, knockout.js

I have a function that is called after button is clicked. it looks like this

```
<button class=".." data-bind="click: $root.openModal">
```

Now I am trying to pass parameters to this function. Resulting in this code

```
<button class=".." data-bind="click: $root.openModal(Object.Keys(params))">
```

Parameters are passed successfully, but now whenever I load the page, before even clicking the button, openModal function is called. Same happens even if I leave '**()**' instead of **openModal(Object.Keys(params))**.

function itself, looks like this

```
self.openModal = function (keys) {
    popupObservable(true);

    self.modal = $.openModalDefault({
        url: '#js-confirmation-dialog-template',
        className: 'doc',
        onLoad: function () {
            popupObservable(false);
            if (!$(selectors.confirmationModal)[0]) {
                return;
            }
            var viewModel = new ConfirmationDialogViewModel(function () {
                self.confirm(keys);
                self.modal.close();
            }, "This part is irrelevant");
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $(selectors.confirmationModal)[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

What is the difference between openModal and openModal() and how do I pass parameters to this function without triggering it on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are invoking the function on `data-bind="click: $root.openModal(Object.Keys(params))"` instead you want to construct a function dynamically with those parameters and execute that on click.

```
self.openModalWithParam = function (keys) {

// keys come from the outer function and returns a function for those values

return function () {
    popupObservable(true);

    self.modal = $.openModalDefault({
        url: '#js-confirmation-dialog-template',
        className: 'doc',
        onLoad: function () {
            popupObservable(false);
            if (!$(selectors.confirmationModal)[0]) {
                return;
            }
            var viewModel = new ConfirmationDialogViewModel(function () {
                self.confirm(keys);
                self.modal.close();
            }, "This part is irrelevant");
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $(selectors.confirmationModal)[0]);
        }
    });
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just pass a function literal as the click handler:

`<button data-bind="click: () => $root.openModal(Object.Keys(params))">`

Which I would personally prefer because it means you don't have to duplicate your `openModal` function.